# What is the maximum number of cigarettes you can place on a table such that they all touch each other?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

A friend of mine came up with this question: What is the maximum number of cigarettes you can place on a table such that they all touch each other? There is one caveat, the cigarettes must be in a stable configuration, i.e. stay balanced.

While it's relatively easy to come up with a solution with 6 cigarettes, it becomes way harder when trying with 7. I was able to find the following 7 cigarettes configuration:
[complete view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfDsh.jpg), [top view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGSMQ.png), [side view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihYKd.jpg).

I'm not sure if this precise configuration is stable, but I'm almost certain that one can slightly move the cigarettes around and make them balanced.

My two questions are the following:

1. Is there a configuration with 8?
2. Are there different configurations with 7 cigarettes (meaning configuration obtained not from just slightly moving the solution in the picture around)?

Comment: By "they all touch each other" do you mean every cigarette touches every other cigarette at least one other cigarette?

Comment: @ClydeKertzer I mean that every cigarette must touch every other cigarette. For example, if you look at my solution and focus on any specific cigarette, you will see that it touches all the other 6

Comment: How do you define "cigarette" geometrically? Otherwise, the question has no geometric meaning.

Comment: @Somos I don't think that's very relevant for my questions as every cigarette looking cylinder will produce pretty much the same kind of configurations, but let me just arbitrarily define them as cylinders with an height to base diameter ratio of 11.5. That's what i used in my model